# Formatting a column using Expression Transformation in Informatica Powercenter

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a Column (SALARY) in Source Table from Relational DB, 
for example 15000 is a record in SALARY column 
and I want to format it as $15,000.00 into the Target table which is a Relational DB
using Expression Transformation.

Thankyou,
Ajay

Comment: Why do you want to do it? Why not store numerical value in the database and then format it properly in the presentation layer?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using below steps:

1. Pull the required column from source to Expression transformation.
2. Create a derived column as the concatenation of $ and the input column by making use of the equation `CONCAT('$',Source_Column)`
3. Load this new column to the target, instead of the column from the source.

***I hope this is just to learn the functionality. In real life scenarios, this is a bad practice. We need not keep these symbols and all in tables. This can be directly handled at reporting level.***

Answer (score 0):

may be the scenario where salary column has salary of different types say 'dollor','euro','pounds', etc in same table. 
still i agree with Thomas Cherian that is not good practice to store the symbol with data itself.

if this is the scenario you can do 2 things.

--1.) add another column in table and store the value of type there or add another column which stores the conversion rate also.

--2.) convert all the values in once currency and store it without symbol.